# How to view all the published resources of my server RESTful web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, tomcat7

I've received a sample **Java** application, which contains some **RESTFul web services**. I've set it up in **eclipse** with **Tomcat** and it's in running state. Unfortunately I haven't received any information about the published Resources. So my question is:
How can I find out all the published resources of my app? Are they printed in any server logs at the time of server startup?

Comment: Are you using Jersey? RESTEasy? CXF?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Jersey is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to know about **WADL** file which serves my purpose. This file is generated automatically by **Jersey-2.22** when the application is up & running. It is accessible by hitting

`http://localhost:8080/<path to application>/application.wadl` and

`http://localhost:8080/<path to application>/application.wadl?detail` in detail.

I've taken `localhost` because the app is deployed on my local machine and `8080` because app is deployed on **Tomcat7** on that port.

Reference: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html